# Why is it not a security hole that PostgreSQL by default stores user passwords in an MD5 hash?

Tags: postgresql, security, hash, md5, internals

Why is it not a security hole that PostgreSQL by default stores user passwords in an MD5 hash? I am studying the internals of PostgreSQL and have gotten to the system catelog [pg_authid](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/catalog-pg-authid.html) and when I read about the MD5 hash encryption it appears that it is regarded as antiquated.  In my thinking if an admin or a user is able to access the underlying file store then they could hypothetically crack the passwords and do whatever said credentials would enable.

I ask why it is not a security hole because apparently PostgreSQL has been "Common Criteria Certified" which seems to be military grade secure according to it's wiki which notes it's provenance from western defense organizations.

Thanks!

Comment: Version 10 will offer [`scram-sha-256` authentication method](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/auth-methods.html#auth-password)

Comment: So is it fair to say there does exist a large security hole in many default installations today?

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto ^

Comment: It is not fair at all. If the hashed passwords fall in the wrong hands the encryption method will be of lessen importance unless it is a costly one.

Comment: @clodoaldoNeto I think I'm being dense perhaps... but if I follow your response correctly it appears that you're saying simply access to the hash is what matters so why encrypt it at all then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, [PostgreSQL 10 adds SCRAM-SHA256](http://paquier.xyz/postgresql-2/postgres-10-scram-authentication/) based on SASL, making this a moot point.

For older versions: It's a weakness, but it's not a large security hole for a number of reasons:

- Internet-deployed PostgreSQL instances should be using SSL, preventing eavesdropping on the protocol. This greatly reduces the chances of successful password theft.
- Passwords are twice-salted. The password stored on disk is hashed with a salt and the md5 digest is taken. But the password sent on the wire is re-salted and re-hashed with an authentication-exchange specific salt, so if you capture a hashed password on the wire you cannot simply replay it in a later authentication.

If you manage to get a few copies of the same twice-salted password by eavesdropping a plaintext connection, you could potentially exploit weaknesses in MD5 to find the once-salted version that's stored on disk, and use that to authenticate with the DB.

But it's a lot of work, and it's pretty much totally prevented by using SSL.

Personally speaking, I think the "Common Criteria" is close to a pile bureaucratic nonsense. It applies only to one specific install with very narrow, specific versions of everything from hardware on up. It should help exclude total snake-oil, but it sure doesn't prove anything is secure. (Hell, look at Government systems...)

Comment: Thanks! It makes sense that the configuration of the database adds a significant layer of security to the system and also I figured they do not just dole out the Common Criteria Certified stamp of approval to any piece of software. Also @Craig Ringer I'm curious where one would learn more about proper deployment processes and also where if at all the second bullet point is documented?

Comment: @johndrinane I'm not sure the details of the md5 authentication handshake in PostgreSQL are documented outside the source code. See `src/backend/libpq/auth.c`

Comment: I will look into adding it to the documentation I guess then ... muchos gracias!

Comment: The point of password hashing is to defend against people gaining access to the stored value. It has nothing to do with MITM attacks. MD5 only offers protection (vs plaintext) to strong passwords.

Comment: @OrangeDog Well, salting and hashing passwords is important to protect against exposure of the stored password yes. But a second, separate layer of hashing is also vital for guarding against MITM replay attacks.